# Adding to custom detector class to apache tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

```
public class CustomDetector implements Detector {

public MediaType detect(InputStream stream, Metadata metadata) throws IOException {
    MediaType type = MediaType.OCTET_STREAM;

    InputStream lookahead = new LookaheadInputStream(stream, 1024);
    try {
        //Detect File Type
        File file = new File("ToolConfig.properties");
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        String filetype = tika.detect(file);

        //Read File content
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("ToolConfig.properties"));
        for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            if (key instanceof String && value instanceof String && filetype.contains("text/plain")) {
                type = MediaType.application("properties");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        lookahead.close();
    }
    return type;
    }
}
```

Using tika I want to detect .properties file as `properties file(text/properties)` based on key and values format present in properties file else as a `text file(text/plain)`

Above I written a custom class which implements Detector interface of tika and also created a custom file for mime type:

```
<mime-info>
<mime-type type="text/properties">
<glob pattern="*.properties"/>
</mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Added the above custom class to a jar file along with `META-INF/services/org.apache.tika.detect.Detector file` but when I run the program Its printing a `.properties` file as text/plain but not as text/properties file

I am not sure what went wrong and there's not much info about adding custom mime or customizing the existing parsers of tika.

Comment: Is Tika seeing your detector? If you ask DefaultDetector for the child detectors, is it seeing yours? Did you correctly list your class's name in the service file?

Comment: I don't know how to check it whether its getting detected or not. could you please help. i am new to this

Comment: Just call [getDetectors()](https://tika.apache.org/1.8/api/org/apache/tika/detect/CompositeDetector.html#getDetectors%28%29) on your DefaultDetector you got from TikaConfig, and it'll tell you!

Comment: There's no method called `getDetectors()` I can only see `getDetector()`. I tried extending my class from compositeDetector and called `getDetectors()` method which return empty array

Comment: `11.2.3 Plugging in new detectors - From the book TIka in Action Chris.A`
The one last thing you need after compiling this custom detector class is to plug it into Tika. The easiest way to do that is to place the compiled class into a JAR archive together with a META-INF/services/org.apache.tika.detect.Detector file that contains the fully qualified name of this class on a line by itself. Then include that JAR in your classpath, and Tika will automatically pick up and use the new detector......I tried this and may be I didn't build the jar file properly

Comment: All the built-in Tika detectors are loaded that same way, so all I can suggest is you look at the Tika source tree to get ideas of how you should do it, and look at the Tika jars to see how it works

Comment: I am using tika-app 1.8 which has all the dependencies required

Comment: Its ok I think I will give up on tika I guess.

Comment: If you're using the app, why are you messing about with a java IDE then? If working with the tika app, you can do it all with a text editor and the command line

Comment: What app my friend? I using a jar file(tika-app 1.8).

Comment: Tika App = tika-app.jar. You are using the tika app if you're using that as a runnable jar

Comment: You might also want to look at [TIKA-1660](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1660) (including the fact that it's already fixed!)

Comment: Ok I will have a look at it tomorrow. I have been searching for a solution for this and even looked at magic numbers to create one.

Comment: @Gagravarr wow that's nice that they fixed properties file now. So do I have to download tika-app 1.8 again to fix this?

Comment: @Gagravarr Looks like they haven't released the updated jar yet

Comment: If you look closely at the dates on that issue, you'll see why there's no official release with that in just yet! For now, you'll either need to download a nightly build, or checkout the source and build yourself

Comment: How do I download the nightly build??

Comment: I'd suggest typing "Tika nightly builds" into google, and follow the top result... It's magic how that normally works...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your XML starts with (some) space(s), try and remove the space(s) at the **very beginning** of the XML, like so:

```
<mime-info>
    <mime-type type="text/properties">
        <glob pattern="*.properties"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

I would prefer that you add an XML declaration at the **very first line** of your file and on the very next line proceed to the instruction I've mentioned above, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mime-info>
    <mime-type type="text/properties">
        <glob pattern="*.properties"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Now Its working but the custom class is not getting called. I mean a properties should be shown as `text/properties` but its showing as `text/plain`

Comment: That is another issue that will require a different SO question. I am not familiar with Apache Tika. I am glad my solution helped. :-)

Comment: Besides, you are reading key/value from `ToolConfig.Properties`. So check in that file what key and value are you returning.

Comment: `DB_NAME 
Africa5`
`DB_USERNAME 
db2inst1` `DB_TYPE
db2` 
`SCHEMA
SELFCARE_TEST` 
`PORT
50002` 
`DB_PASSWORD
32A74934D1 4` 
`IP
192.168.6.97`

Comment: Its returning strings as above